# Cannot get the desired output in R

Tags: r, if-statement

I'm trying to add a Fav column in x, which gives app if x2 is more than 50%.
But, i don't get any column added. please help.

```
x<- data.frame(x1=c(1,2,3,4,5),x2=c(2,3,4,5,6),x3=c(3,2,5,2,5))

x$x2per <- (x$x2/(x$x2+x$x3))*100
x$x3per <- (x$x3/(x$x2+x$x3))*100

if(x$x2per>50){
  x$Fav <- "App"
}
else x$Fav<-"LF"
```

I get the below output.

```
Warning message:
In if (x$x2per > 50) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
> x
  x1 x2 x3    x2per    x3per
1  1  2  3 40.00000 60.00000
2  2  3  2 60.00000 40.00000
3  3  4  5 44.44444 55.55556
4  4  5  2 71.42857 28.57143
5  5  6  5 54.54545 45.45455
>
```

Comment: x2$x2per is a vector and not a number. your calculations above are resulting in vectors and not numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you could assign all observations one value and then overwrite in case they meet your criteria on `x2per`.

```
x$Fav <- "LF"
x$Fav[x$Fav > 50] <- "App"
```

If you want your `if` loop to work, you will need to use indexing.

```
x$Fav <- NA
for (i in 1:nrow(x)) {
  if(x$x2per[i] > 50) {
    x$Fav[i] <- "App"
  }
  } else {
    x$Fav[i] <- "LF"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `ifelse` for vectorized if statement

```
x$Fav <- ifelse(x$x2per > 50, "APP", "LF")
```